# Use End Effector frame to move in moveit

Tags: ros, python, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello:

I use `moveit_commander` to make a cartesian move on the X axis, but the camera on the gripper sees that not only the X axis is moved.

I checked and found that the moveit preset uses the 'world' frame, the world frame and Link6 frame poses are not the same, and I should be doing cartesian movement on the Link6(End Effector) frame.

I checked using `rosrun tf tf_echo Link6 world` and sure this is what I need, but I don't know how to replace the frame that moveit uses, any pointers or instructions?

I found this discussion and it seems to be what I want to do.But using C++, is it possible to do the same thing with Python?

https://answers.ros.org/question/228190/moveit-end-effector-positioning/

Thanks in advance

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407387/use-end-effector-frame-to-move-in-moveit/) by [Gojigu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90776/gojigu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can do this in moveit_commander. Here are two possible approaches:

1. Determine the new pose within in the eef frame, then transform that pose into the `world` frame, then use it as the cartesian goal. See the answer to #q323075 for python code to transform a pose. One thing that answer gets wrong is that in a real app the `tfbuffer` and `listener` objects should be created only once (and not be destroyed at the end of their `transform_pose()` function.)
2. Use the moveit_commander `set_pose_reference_frame()` method to select the eef frame, then use a goal pose within that frame. I suspect this method is rarely used, so you may discover bugs with it. Disclosure: I've never actually tried to do it this way.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gojigu](https://answers.ros.org/users/90776/gojigu/) on 2022-10-09**:
Thanks for your reply.

Method 1 is what I need!

Method 2 seems easier to use, but I can't get it to work, there's not much information on the web about this command.